# Why is this code not working?

Tags: javascript

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work. I know you can put a function inside a function in Javascript. I don't know what else to do. Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Slideshow Webpage</title>
<script>
 var sound = new Audio ("Get low.mp3");


 function startTimer() {

 setTimeout(countnine, 1000);
 setTimeout(counteight, 2000);

 function ten() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="10";
 }

 function nine() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="9";
 }

 function eight() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="8";
 }

 function seven() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="7";
 }

 function six() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="6";
 }

 function five() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="5";
 }

 function four() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="4";
 }

 function three() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="3";
 }

 function two() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="2";
 }

 function one() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="1";
 }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing this website for a webpage</h1>
<p>This is just a test. I am testing this website out to make a webpage.                  </p>

<div id="timer">
<p id="timerText"></p>
</div>

<p onclick="startTimer()">Start timer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me what I am doing wrong in this?

Comment: you need to state your problem, what you are trying to do? and what is happening

Comment: `countnine` and `counteight` don't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: `counteight` and `countnine` don't exist AFAIK

Comment: there are no functions named `counteight` in your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3279hw8m/1/

Answer (score 3):

You don´t need call any setTimeout for second, use setTimeout. Like this exemple

```js
function startTimer(){
var count = 10;
var time = setInterval(function(){
   
  if(count==0){
    clearInterval(time)
  }
   document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML=count--
},1000)

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Slideshow Webpage</title>
<script>
 var sound = new Audio ("Get low.mp3");


</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing this website for a webpage</h1>
<p>This is just a test. I am testing this website out to make a webpage.                  </p>

<div id="timer">
<p id="timerText"></p>
</div>

<p onclick="startTimer()">Start timer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Slideshow Webpage</title>
<script>
 var sound = new Audio ("Get low.mp3");


 function startTimer() {
 
 setTimeout(nine, 1000);
 setTimeout(eight, 2000);

 function ten() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="10";
 }

 function nine() {
 
 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="9";
 }

 function eight() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="8";
 }

 function seven() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="7";
 }

 function six() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="6";
 }

 function five() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="5";
 }

 function four() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="4";
 }

 function three() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="3";
 }

 function two() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="2";
 }

 function one() {

 document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML="1";
 }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing this website for a webpage</h1>
<p>This is just a test. I am testing this website out to make a webpage.                  </p>

<div id="timer">
<p id="timerText"></p>
</div>

<p onclick="startTimer()">Start timer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should he use this code? What was wrong with his code, and what did you change to fix it?